# Error 'undefined right operand of 'in' is not an object' when implementing in-app purchases in React Native using react-native-iap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Title:

```
"Error 'undefined right operand of 'in' is not an object' when implementing in-app purchases in React Native using react-native-iap"
```

Description:
I'm encountering an issue while trying to implement in-app purchases in my React Native application for Android using the react-native-iap library. The application is configured with different product SKUs, and I'm receiving the **error** 'undefined right operand of 'in' is not an object' when attempting to make a purchase.

App Configuration:

"react-native": "0.73.4"
"react-native-iap": "^12.12.2"
Emulator: Android Pixel 7 Pro API 27
Additional Details:

The products are active in my Google Play Console.
I have an .aab file activated in my Play Store.

```
// Importing react-native-iap
import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';

// Definition of product SKUs
const itemSkus = Platform.select({
  android: {
    skus: [
      'plan_intermedio',
      'plan_avanzado',
      'plan_exclusiva'
    ]
  }
});

// State hook to store products
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

// Side effect to initialize the connection and fetch products
useEffect(() => {
  RNIap.initConnection().catch(() => {
    console.log('error connecting to the store...');
  });
  getProducts();

  return () => {
    RNIap.endConnection(); // Make sure to close the store connection when the component unmounts
  };
}, []);

// Function to fetch products
const getProducts = async () => {
  try {
    if (itemSkus) {
      const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
      setProducts(products);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('error', err);
  }
};

// Function to make a purchase
const buyProduct = async (skus) => {
  try {
    const product = skus.productId;
    const purchase = await RNIap.requestPurchase(product, false);
    console.log(purchase);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err.code, err.message);
  }
};

// UI snippet
<View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => buyProduct(showProducts)}>
    <Text style={{ color: '#000', backgroundColor:'#fff', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      Comprar
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Problem:
When attempting to make a purchase using react-native-iap, I receive the error 'undefined right operand of 'in' is not an object.' I've thoroughly reviewed my code, SKU configuration, and attempted various solutions, but the issue persists.

Attempts to Solve:

Reviewed and ensured correct SKU configuration for Android.
Verified proper initialization and closure of the react-native-iap library.
Checked product fetching logic using RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus) for valid product information.
Examined the purchase function (buyProduct) to ensure the correct SKU is passed to RNIap.requestPurchase().
Despite these efforts, I'm still seeking guidance on identifying and resolving the root cause of the error.